# Change previous sibling value with php xPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a situation that's driving me crazy. I want to search my feed for an element with a certain value (deriving from an array) and if that value is found, change the value of it's previous sibling element.

My feed looks like this

```
<products>
    <product>
        <properties>
            <property name="category">
                <value>Fruits</value>
            </property>
            <property name="item">
                <value>Banana</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </product>
    <product>
        <properties>
            <property name="category">
                <value>Fruits</value>
            </property>
            <property name="item">
                <value>Apple</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </product>
    <product>
        <properties>
            <property name="category">
                <value>Fruits</value>
            </property>
            <property name="item">
                <value>Carrot</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </product>
</products>
```

As you can see, there can be some errors in the feed. For these instances i made an array with the appropriate value, like so:

```
$replacements = Array(
    "Carrot" => "Vegetable"
);
```

Now i thought to select every `property` with the attribute `item` that has the value as in `$replacements`'s key, then select the previous sibling element with the attribute `category` and change this value with the matching `$replacements`'s value.

I came up with this, but that only gives me a white screen with no output at all

```
$xml_src = 'feed.xml';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xml_src);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$query = '//property[@name = "item"]';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    if(array_key_exists($entry->nodeValue,$replacements)){
        $entry->previousSibling->previousSibling->nodeValue = $replacements[$entries->nodeValue];
    }
}
```

But i don't understand why it doesn't output anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple things a bit off here:

```
array_key_exists($entry->nodeValue,$replacements)
```

The nodeValue is going to contain all the text content within the property element and its descendants - including newlines and spaces.

```
... = $replacements[$entries->nodeValue];
```

You're likely looking for `$replacements[$entry->nodeValue]` but again you've got the same problem as above with the white space. Not only that but you'd be replacing the entirety of the prior property's nodeValue with text so:

```
<property name="category">
    <value>Fruits</value>
</property>
```

would become just:

```
<property name="category">Vegetable</property>
```

---

To fix it all up I'd recommend adjusting the query, as well as how you're addressing the target value to replace in order to get rid of the `->previousSibling->previousSibling` chaining and be a bit more explicit.

#### Example:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//property[@name="item"]/value') as $node) {
    if (array_key_exists(trim($node->textContent), $replacements)) {

        $target = $xpath->query(
            'preceding-sibling::property/value/text()',
            $node->parentNode
        )->item(0);

        $target->parentNode->replaceChild(
            $dom->createTextNode($replacements[trim($node->textContent)]),
            $target
        );

    }
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

#### Output:

```
    ...
    <product>
        <properties>
            <property name="category">
                <value>Vegetable</value>
            </property>
            <property name="item">
                <value>Carrot</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return **Value** and in order to do that you need to correct your query to this

```
$query = '//property[@name = "item"]/value';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the complete path, so:

```
$query = '//products/product/properties/property[@name = "item"]/value';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    if(array_key_exists($entry->nodeValue,$replacements)){
        $entry->previousSibling->previousSibling->nodeValue = $replacements[$entries->nodeValue];
    }
}
```

Also, you can try to use a `context` ([Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)):

```
$context = $document->getElementsByTagName('products')->item(0);
$query = './/property[@name = "item"]/value';//add a '.' before the query to make it relative to the context
$entries = $xpath->query($query, $context);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    if(array_key_exists($entry->nodeValue,$replacements)){
        $entry->previousSibling->previousSibling->nodeValue = $replacements[$entries->nodeValue];
    }
}
```

Both solutions work for me in very similar situations.